# persistant live-USB doesn't save my wifi password

Tags: live-usb, settings, persistence

I have a persistant live-USB with an almost empty `casper-rw` part. And I know the persistant part works because when I open firefox, it opens the tabs from my last session. But each time I reboot, I have to reselect my wifi and to re-enter my wifi password. So my question is:
How can I save my wifi settings on a persistant live-usb?

I only have a `casper-rw` but not a `home-rw` that is mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/283265/473020) (or at least it doesn't show up in the file explorer). Is this the reason? If yes, how can I create this `home-rw` without reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch

It is an Ubuntu 20.04 live usb

Comment: Home-rw is completely optional, Is your casper-rw a file or partition? What version of Ubuntu are you using? 20.04 uses a persistent file named "writable" instead of "casper-rw" but a partition named "casper-rw" should still work. To be safe change the persistent partition label to "writable". What tool did you use to make your drive? the link you posted is old and things have changed with persistence.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, thanks for your help, but the next time I rebooted everything was saved including the wifi settings. I don't understand what happened because I didn't change any settings but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next time I rebooted everything was saved including the wifi settings. I don't understand what happened because I didn't change any settings but at least it's working now.

Comment: The first boot of a persistent flash drive just populates the casper-rw, (writable), partition with folders needed to hold the persistent data, The folders are named "upper" and "work". Further boots of the drive are persistent. Glad it is now working for you. Thank you for letting us know it worked. +1